# Error Configuring TFS 2010 Beta: No access to TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am trying to run the "Custom Configuration" on my TFS 2010 beta install.

After it runs, I get the following error:

**Error TF255125:Metabase access to the following resource could not be granted: TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG**

Does anyone know what this is or what I can do to grant access so my configuration can run successfully?

I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2 RC 64 bit (in VMWare Server).

Comment: Posted on Connect at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=456243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by having a server that has a name longer than 15 chars.  A longer name is truncated by the netbios and ends up causing this error.

The solution is make sure your machine names are under 15 chars.